# 555 timer oscillator circuit

Tags: oscillator, timer, 555, astable

How can i get 50% duty cycles?[image]

Comment: Funnily enough the linked "duplicate" doesn't have the classic answer, which is Andy's second circuit, which works very well if the output isn't heavily loaded.

Comment: Is there other methods to do it? can i  change the resistor value or capacitor?

Answer (score 5):

Try this: -

[image]

R1 dictates charge time of C1 and R2 dictates the discharge time.

Or this: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc44.php)

Alternatively put a d type flip-flop on the output to divide the frequency by two and deliver a very good 50% duty cycle.

Comment: Is there other methods to do it? For example by changing the resistor value or capacitor value?

Comment: You cannot ever achieve a perfect 50% duty cycle with the standard circuit because charging the capacitor is done via two resistors whilst discharge is done via one resistor so, duty can be nearly 50% to nearly 100% with the standard circuit no matter how hard you try to change any value.